# How to solve an optimization problem using Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have an excel file with the numbers 1-9, each number on a different cell down column A. I'm trying to solve the optimization problem:

Max C^T x
s.t. Ax <= b
x >= 0

where B is the 3x1 matrix [5 10 15]
C is the 1x2 matrix [1,-2]
and A is the 3x2 matrix 
[4 5
6 7
8 9]

The Gurobi code must also read the excel file to obtain these values.

I'm not sure how to approach this, but I think it should be something like
Max (1x1-2x2) 
S.T. 4x1+5x2<=3 
6x3+7x4<=14 
8x5+9x6<=10

How should I keep going / is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in or ready-made solution for this problem. There are simply way too many ways to organize your data in Excel sheets to standardize this.

You would first need to get your data organized. I suggest parsing the Excel table using a Python tool:

- https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-excel-spreadsheets-in-python/
- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/
- https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Then, it should be straightforward to code the mathematical model using Gurobi's Python interface.

The easiest way is probably via [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html?highlight=excel#excel). There is even an example demonstrating that use case with the Excel import function from pandas: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/examples/diet4_py.html